# Python Mechanize keeps giving me 'response_seek_wrapper' when I try to use .open

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm not sure what's going on, as the script used to work (before I messed around with my python on my system...)

But when I try something along the lines of

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open("http://google.com")
```

I get something like

```
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x10123fd88 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x101232170 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1010bf5f0>>>
```

Does anyone know why this is and what the fix is?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not an exception, is it?
nothing wrong is happening, you just got a return value, which is esentially a response object, equivalent to `br.response()`.

see

```
>>> r = browser.open("http://google.com")
>>> r
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x9bb116c whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x9bb426c whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9ba306c>>>
>>> r.info().headers
# see the response headers
```

vs

```
>>> browser.open("http://google.com")
>>> browser.response()
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x9c229cc whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x9bb426c whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9ba306c>>>
>>> browser.response().info().headers
# see the response headers
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I just alwats used r = browser.open, which never gave that response. thanks!

Comment: @Parker no problem, i was also little bit scared, when i saw this object first time :)